# Is the volume of an k-parallelogram determined by its edge lengths and angles

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

It is easy to show that the volume of a $3$-parallelogram $P$ is purely a function of the edge lengths and the angles, simply by computing the square root of the determinant of the gram matrix of $A$ (where the columns of $A$ are the edge vectors of $P$) and observing that its value depends only on the multiset of edge lengths and angles.

Is this true for $k>3$?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I didn't understand your question but... Yes the determinant of the Gram matrix is equal to the volume of the corresponding parallelotope. Since the entries of the Gram matrix are inner products of vectors which are completely defined by the lenghts and angles of the corresponding vectors, then yes the volume depenends only on the lengths and angles of the vectors.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram_determinant

Comment: I'm asking if you are just given the "bag of lengths and angles" whether you can figure out the volume. That's not obvious from the Gram matrix, which depends on knowledge of the vectors.

Comment: Sorry, didnt understand after all. For the lengths you vertainly dont need to know which vectors they correspond to. The length of a vector $a$ multiplies the entries of the corresponding row and column of the Gram matrix $K$. Since multiplying the row (or column) of a matrix by a constant $c$ results in a matrix whose determinant  is $c|K|$, it doesnt matter which row it multiplies.